# NS SuiteQl Suitelet Query for geting info of Invoice and Corresponding Payment transaction

Tags: mysql, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am New to NetSuite,

I am trying to fetch the Invoice, bills and their corresponding payments and show it in report,

I tried creating the saved search, It was successful, but we need to archive the same via Suitelet script Query,

Saved Search Result:
[image]

Query for saved search:
[image]
[image]

The problem is when I used the SQL, The NS is not providing the Payment ID in JSON response of Paid transaction

Is there any other way to archive this?

The Basic query I used is :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM

    TransactionLine
    
WHERE
    ( Transaction.TranID= '2535') AND (Transaction.AbbrevType= ('INV'))
```

I am trying to create the same result as per the saved search output. So i use the above script to get the invoice Table, but the table does not contain any paymentID  to fetch its related payment records of Paid Invoice.

Is there any other way to fetch the Payment Transaction of Invoices Using suiteQL

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT VP.TRANSACTION_ID FROM  TRANSACTIONS      V 
        LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION_LINKS AP ON AP.ORIGINAL_TRANSACTION_ID = V.TRANSACTION_ID AND LINK_TYPE = 'Payment'
        LEFT JOIN TRANSACTIONS   VP ON AP.APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ID=VP.TRANSACTION_ID
        
        WHERE V.TRANSACTION_ID=2535
```